# Android Studio - Listview OnClick Activates Multiple Checkboxes

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, checkbox

Hello  im a beginner in Androidstudio.

I tried to create a Listview with a Checkbox and a TextView
On first glance it looks like it worked but the Problem is I check the Checkbox of "My Note: 0" and the Checkbox of "My Note: 9" is checked,I have no Idea why and debugging does not help.

Not only  Note 9 is cheked every : Multiple of 8 +1 is Checked .
So some checked ones are 9, 17, 25 ,33,41,49,57,65,73,81......

[image]

ListView XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <CheckBox android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox_shopEntry"
        android:layout_weight="90"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="10">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_feedbackName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:fontFamily="casual"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:text="TextView1" />


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

The ListView Adapter :

```
package com.example.fragment.Entity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import com.example.fragment.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;



public class ShopListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ShoppingEntry> {

    private static final String TAG = "ShopListAdapter";

    private Context mContext;
    private int mResource;
    private int lastPosition = -1;

    /**
     * Holds variables in a View
     */
    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        CheckBox checkBox;
    }

    public ShopListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<ShoppingEntry> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        mContext = context;
        mResource = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(@Nullable ShoppingEntry object) {
        super.add(object);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //get the shop list information
        String name = getItem(position).getName();


        //Create the shopEntry object with the information
        ShoppingEntry shopEntry = new ShoppingEntry(name);

        //create the view result for showing the animation
        final View result;

        //ViewHolder object
        ViewHolder holder;


        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);
            holder= new ViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_feedbackName);
            holder.checkBox = convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_shopEntry);

            result = convertView;

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            result = convertView;
        }




        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext,
                (position > lastPosition) ? R.anim.load_down_anim : R.anim.load_up_anim);
        result.startAnimation(animation);
        lastPosition = position;

        holder.name.setText(shopEntry.getName());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

And the Object used in the Adapter

```
package com.example.fragment.Entity;


public class ShoppingEntry {
    private String name;


    public ShoppingEntry(String note) {
        this.name = note;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

}

Comment: Why you are not using recyclerView instead? recyclerView will work fine. and another thing is you don't need to add textView with a checkbox. you can add text on the checkbox. a checkbox has itself text property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're facing has to do with the way `ListView` recycles views.

You're probably aware of this already as you've implemented the `getView()` method with this in mind:

```
    if(convertView == null){
        // Inflate a new View
    }
    else{
        // reuse the recylced view
    }
```

So the `ListView` only renders as many items as needed to fill the screen. It doesn't create more items until you start scrolling and when you *do* start scrolling, the `ListView` starts reusing already inflated views that went out of the screen.

So when you scroll down, the View for Note 0 goes out of screen and `ListView` reuses that for Note 9 which is about to enter the screen.

This would have resulted in you seeing "My Note: 0" show up again from the bottom but your code is already handling this problem by re-setting the item's text appropriately with the correct number:

```
holder.name.setText(shopEntry.getName());
```

But it's still the exact same View object that was used for Note 0. Even if you did update the text with the correct number "9", the state of the checkbox remains the same as it did for Note 0 because it's still the same object.

To solve this issue you will need to do 2 things:

1. Store the 'checked' state of each Shop Entry item somewhere
2. Inisde `getView()`, set the checkbox's state to the checked state of the entry in question

Something like this:

```
// Store a list of checked items. Update as items are checked/unchecked
private ArrayList<ShopEntry> checkedEntries = new ArrayList();

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    .
    .
    .

    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);
        holder= new ViewHolder();
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_feedbackName);
        holder.checkBox = convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_shopEntry);

        // Update the list of checked items when the user checks or unchecks an item
        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked && !checkedEntries.contains(shopEntry)) {
                    checkedEntries.add(shopEntry);
                } else {
                    checkedEntries.remove(shopEntry);
                }
            }
        });

        result = convertView;

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        result = convertView;
    }

    .
    .
    .


    holder.name.setText(shopEntry.getName());
    // reset the checbkox state too!
    holder.checkBox.setChecked(checkedEntries.contains(shopEntry));

    return convertView;
}
```

Warning: I don't have Android Studio installed on the system I'm writing this from so I haven't tested this code. Sorry for that. But I hope I conveyed the general idea. You might want to implement the whole "keep track of which items are checked" thing in your own (better) way.

Answer (score 0):

I have mostly worked on recycler view, but i have fixed this issue , just replace your adapter class

```
 class ShopListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ShoppingEntry> {

private static final String TAG = "ShopListAdapter";
private Context mContext;
ArrayList<ShoppingEntry> mList=new ArrayList<>();

public ShopListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ShoppingEntry> list) {
    super(context, R.layout.item_checkbox_issue, list);
    mContext = context;
    mList.addAll(list);
}

@Override
public void add(@Nullable ShoppingEntry object) {
    super.add(object);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


       TextView textView;
       CheckBox checkbox;

        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_checkbox_issue, parent, false);
        textView =  convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_feedbackName);
        checkbox = convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_shopEntry);
        boolean checked= mList.get(position).isChecked();
        String name = mList.get(position).getName();
        checkbox.setChecked(checked);
        textView.setText(name);

        checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                    mList.get(position).setChecked(isChecked);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

        });

    return convertView;
}
```

and take a variable isselected in your model, because it's manage checked and  unchecked widget for particluer position

```
 class ShoppingEntry {
private String name;

private  boolean isChecked;


public ShoppingEntry(String note, boolean isChecked) {
    this.name = note;
    this.isChecked = isChecked;
}

public boolean isChecked() {
    return isChecked;
}

public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
    isChecked = checked;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}